# JodaTime: format date with 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. day

Tags: scala, jodatime

Does JodaTime provide this functionality? Am unable to find in the docs, perhaps I missed something? [Formatting API doc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) does not show such a feature.

If not, what, parse the resultant string and match against day, appending st,nd,th accordingly?

Seems hackish, thought a library as comprehensive and wonderful as JodaTime (it does rock ;-)) would provide this seemingly simple feature.

Answer (score 19):

While Joda does not implement this directly you don't need an external library, just resort to a simple implementation like this.

```
/**
 * Returns the correct suffix for the last digit (1st, 2nd, .. , 13th, .. , 23rd)
 */
public static String getLastDigitSufix(int number) {
    switch( (number<20) ? number : number%10 ) {
        case 1 : return "st";
        case 2 : return "nd";
        case 3 : return "rd";
        default : return "th";
    }
}
```

In response to MHaris, the above code produces

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    System.out.print(i + getLastDigitSufix(i) + ", ");
}

0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th, 8th, 9th, 
10th, 11th, 12th, 13th, 14th, 15th, 16th, 17th, 18th, 19th, 
20th, 21st, 22nd, 23rd, 24th, 25th, 26th, 27th, 28th, 29th, 
30th, 31st, 32nd, 33rd, 34th, 35th, 36th, 37th, 38th, 39th, 
40th, 41st, 42nd, 43rd, 44th, 45th, 46th, 47th, 48th, 49th, 
50th, 51st, 52nd, 53rd, 54th, 55th, 56th, 57th, 58th, 59th, 
60th, 61st, 62nd, 63rd, 64th, 65th, 66th, 67th, 68th, 69th, 
70th, 71st, 72nd, 73rd, 74th, 75th, 76th, 77th, 78th, 79th, 
80th, 81st, 82nd, 83rd, 84th, 85th, 86th, 87th, 88th, 89th, 
90th, 91st, 92nd, 93rd, 94th, 95th, 96th, 97th, 98th, 99th
```

Which, according to [English Ordinals in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_numerals#Ordinal_numbers) looks correct.

Comment: You may also have been downvoted because the simple implementation was wrong - this code snippet produces "11st", "12nd" and "13rd", all of which should have the suffix "th".
I'd edit the post, but the queue is apparently full.

Comment: @MHarris glad you didn't edit. Looks good, check for yourself! :)

Comment: Oh, very nice! Looks great, my bad. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/), which is built on top of JodaTime.

Comment: +1 but, man, just trying to get this project out the door, don't throw more deps at me ;-)